# MCU and ADC fault handling in production code

Tags: adc, autosar, faulthandler

I am using S32k3xx ECU with mcal drivers from nxp. I want to handle the real time faults of adc and mcu in production code so read faults from adc using register/structure and passing this fault to DEM. So I want to know what is the Autosar standerd to read faults from adc/mcu and pass to dem for further process.
we are handling faults like ADC_Init timeout fault, ADC calibraation Timeout and Conversion Timeout fault. So please help to know this as soon as possible.
Thank you in advance.

regards,
Pooja